# "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1

Tags: docker

yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1 expected , but found ''   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 3
please help me find the error

```
version:"3"
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    web:
      build: .
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

[image: code snippet]

Comment: Please include formatted code in the body of your question. You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code. More formatting help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is off, version and services need to be on the same level. And you're missing a space between `version:` and `"3"`.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Try some online YAML validator ([like this one on codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator)) to check for those errors next time.